# Rails の find_by_sql でコロン（：）を利用する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails の find_by_sql を用いて
`SomeModel.find_by_sql(["SELECT 1 FROM ip_addrs WHERE ip_addr = ':FFFF' AND id = :id", {id: 1}])`
といった、SQL内にコロンを含む、かつ、パラメータ名の置換を行うケースを実行したいのですが、SQL内のコロンが置換とみなされてしまいエラーが発生してしまいます

通常のコロンと、置換のためのコロンを区別するようなエスケープの方法は提供されていないのでしょうか？

Comment: `{id: 1, FFFF: ':FFFF'}` だといけて、かつ、これしか解法がなさそうなイメージ。。

Comment: ip_addr部分は 0000 ~ FFFF までの組み合わせがあるので 65536 通りのキーを記述せねばならないですね...

Comment: む、ということは、特定の ip_addr で抽出したいのではなく、ip_addr は変わる可能性があるということでしょうか？　であれば逆に変数として扱うことになって hash として渡すことになりそうですが……。

Comment: 記述する ip_addr の数は動的に変わる場合を想定しています
(ip_addr, ip_addr_from, ip_addr_to) の組が複数存在し、すべての組で ip_addr BETWEEN ip_addr_from AND ip_addr_to を満たすことを確かめるようなケースです

Comment: ?を使うプレースホルダーで実現できませんか？ `SomeModel.find_by_sql(["SELECT 1 FROM ip_addrs WHERE ip_addr = ':FFFF' AND id = ?", 1])`

Answer (score -1):

```
SomeModel.find_by_sql(["SELECT 1 FROM ip_addrs WHERE ip_addr = CONCAT(':', 'FFFF') AND id = :id", {id: 1}])
```

のように SQL 層での文字列連結文法に書き換えることで、コロンの直後に [a-zA-Z] が出現することを回避できます
ActiveRecord::Sanitization::ClassMethods.replace_named_bind_variables の正規表現にマッチしなくなるため、SQLの文字列中のコロンを rails による破壊から保護することができます